# Bold italic vectors with isomath and newtxmath

Tags: newtxmath, isomath

I am trying to get bold italic vectors with the newtxmath font.

Using other fonts I can just load the isomath package and then use `\vectorsym{...}` to get the desired output.

However, in combination with the newtxmath package, `\vectorsym` has no effect at all.

Below is my MWE which produces two identical non-bold letters x, while I am expecting the second to be bold.

I am loading the font stack according to example 2 on page 17 of the manual
https://mirror.funkfreundelandshut.de/latex/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf

I know, I could redefine `\vectorsym` with the aid of `\bm` but this produces another issue in my actual application, and I thought the point of isomath was that you load it and it takes care of everything...

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% page 17 in manual
\usepackage[lining,semibold]{libertine} % a bit lighter than Times--no osf in math
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % best for Western European languages
\usepackage{textcomp} % required to get special symbols
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% a typewriter font must be defined
\usepackage{amsmath}% must be loaded before amsthm, if using
\usepackage{amsthm}% must be loaded before newtxmath
\usepackage[libertine,vvarbb,slantedGreek]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{bm}% load after all math to give access to bold math
%After loading math package, switch to osf in text.
\useosf % for osf in normal text

\usepackage{isomath}

\begin{document}
    $x \vectorsym{x}$   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The `textcomp` package needn't be loaded unless your TeX distribution hasn't been updated in five or more years. Back in 2018, the package's capabilities were fully integrated into the LaTeX kernel. Hence, the comment next to the `\usepackage{textcomp}` instruction -- "required to get special symbols" -- no longer applies. In a similar vein, the option `utf8` is the *default* for the `inputenc` package; hence, there's no need to run `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` either, unless your TeX distribution hasn't been updated in several years...

Comment: `\usepackage{bm}% load after all math to give access to bold math` so after isomath

Comment: @DavidCarlisle nope, that does not change anything about `\vectorsym` not being bold.

Comment: @Bastian I know, I was going to post an answer about that, but egreg posted first, but the comment in your document should be followed, bm should be loaded later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `isomath` does

```
\ifisomath@reuseMathAlphabets
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OML}{\isomath@rmdefault}{bx}{it}
  \def\mathbfit{\mathbf}
\else
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfit}{OML}{\isomath@rmdefault}{bx}{it}
\fi
```

and indeed you get

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OML/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OML/nxlmi/m/it' instead on input line 21.
```

The `isomath` package makes some assumptions that aren't satisfied when `newtxmath` is loaded. Change yourself the definition of `\mathbfit`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[lining,semibold]{libertine} % a bit lighter than Times--no osf in math
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % best for Western European languages
\usepackage{textcomp} % required to get special symbols
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% a typewriter font must be defined
\usepackage{amsmath}% must be loaded before amsthm, if using
\usepackage{amsthm}% must be loaded before newtxmath
\usepackage[libertine,vvarbb,slantedGreek]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{bm}% load after all math to give access to bold math

\usepackage{isomath}


\useosf % for osf in normal text

% fix \mathbfit
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfit}{OML}{nxlmi}{bx}{it}

\begin{document}

$x \vectorsym{x}$   

\end{document}
```

[image]